# Two separate functions of 5282 RC remote?

Tags: technic, remote-control, lighting

Given the RC set of 5282 and 6272c01 below:

[image: 5282] [image: 6272c01]

Is there a solution to use the two paddles that command the auxiliary output of the receiver for different functions?

For reference, see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQOJSqTF1cM) at 1:45.

I'm trying to light two different 8870 led lights, one with the left paddle, the other with the right paddle.

[image]

Comment: Since the lights turn on for both directions, you would need a way to only pass current to them if the current is running in one direction. I'm not sure if there is a way to do that.

Comment: I hoped there are two circuits there, one for each paddle, but the new cables weren't wired to support that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With only using existing non-modified LEGO parts a mechanical solution with a servo motor, two polarization switches and cluch gears is thinkable, but this is all really cumbersome...

It's a bit ironic really, there's a bit of (trivial) circuitry in the 2x2 black brick before the wires of the LED lights split that causes the LEDs to work no-matter the polarization, because LEDs by their nature only work when the correct polarization is applied...

One solution would be to modify the circuitry in the 2x2 plate.

Schematics are here:
http://www.philohome.com/pf/pflights.htm

What basically needs to happen is that the diode bridge is removed and the C1 wire is soldered through to the + side of the leds (to the resistors) and the C2 wire to - side ...

Same for the other pair of leds but switching C1 and C2...

Comment: Do you mean that 6272c01 does output differently depending on the pressed paddle?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is the case. Don't have one to test myself but you could test yourself by attaching a motor. I believe the motor will turn in different directions when pressing the different paddles.

Comment: Indeed, the motor turns as you expect.

Comment: I think it would be fun to modify a pf LED set so the diode bridge is short-circuited and switch the cables of one of the LEDs. Only one of the pair of LEDs would light up depending on which paddle is pressed...

Comment: Would be fun if I had any knowledge on the field, but I haven't. I understand the technical reason, though.

Comment: + I've planned to have one led set per side, meaning one set for right, other for left... still, not mandatory this way.

Comment: Besides the mechanical solution (PF switches driven by a motor) there are no lego components I'm aware of that can do what you want without modifying them.
If you are willing to modify them, anything is possible and the modifications are straightforward for anyone with an electronics background...

Comment: Any third party then?

Comment: Can't imagine a third party offering this off the shelf.
However, shouldn't be to hard to find a person with an electronics background in your vicinity that would be willing to do the modifications to the LEDs for a bit of spending money...
I could do this for you, but I don't know where you from and hence if it's worth the shipping costs...

Comment: Another thing to note, if you modify the leds to short-circuit the diode bridge, the leds would burn a bit brighter as the diode bridge also has some resistance...